# I have a problem adding a custom app address in gnosis-safe app

Tags: gnosis-safe

When I start the service locally and add the locahost address, it is normal for access. However, after I deploy it to the server, I cannot find the manifest.json when filling in the server web address in the custom app. It shows that I have introduced the cross-domain file and provided relevant help. I also tried it and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. add the crossorigin="use-credentials" attribute to the manifest's link element.

```
<link rel="manifest" href=”manifest.json” crossorigin="use-credentials" />
```

2. check your manifest.json location
3. Configure  [Cross-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)  on the server